# Join relation giving the model not found error

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am trying to retrieve the comment and the user of that comment. I have following relations between user and a comment.

This is what I am trying

$users = Comment::with('user')->get();

But I am getting

```
Class 'User' not found
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Any help is appreciated.

### Comment

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;
use App\Event;

class Comment extends Model
{
        // Table Name
    protected $table = 'comments';
        //primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'event_id', 'comment', 'deleted_at'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

### User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }


    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) 
    {
        return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

with

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: yes I sorted out using App\User but why use App\User didnot work

Comment: It will not work because relationship class is in single quote `' '`

Comment: About `use App\User` i am not sure if we can use that instance using `return $this->belongsTo(User);` by removing single quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

or

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

if use this then no need to define `use App\User;`

hope it works.

thanks